# "An alternative mean" or "An alternative means"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am not sure if I should use "an alternative *mean* for..." or "an alternative *means* for..."
to express another way of doing something.
Since I use "an", I feel it is nature to use the singular form "*mean*".
But several people insist it should be the latter. Which one is right?

Comment: Good One. I'm sure that was a joke. It did make me laugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite ending with an *s*, *means* is (or can be) singular. *An alternative means* is no different from *a means to an end*, *a means of communication*, etc.

[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/means):

> **means**  (miːnz)
>
> — n
>   1.  ( functioning as singular or plural ) the medium, method, or instrument used to obtain a result or achieve an end: a means of communication

Comment: Do you mean that "mean" cannot be used to mean "means"? E.g. would "I have a mean to do it." be grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*Means*, since one definition of "means" is *method*.

Comment: I don't understand why you've flagged this as not-an-answer, user49727. It appears to answer the question quite succinctly.

Comment: Thank you, Bradd Szonye. I didn't understand why he commented that either. And why he flagged my answer as such is unfathomable! Anyhow, it's great to know that there are devoted users on this site.